# Overriding Public folder based on namespace Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, overriding, public, directory-structure

After searching for hours, I am posting my first question on Stack Overflow.

**Given:** I have the following route.rb:

```
 resource: :non_namespaced_resource

 namespace :namespaced_resource do  # an example could be :admin
   resources :one_nested_resource
   resources :another_nested_resource
 end
```

**Desired Outcome:** Is to have namespaced resources use its own assets and non-namespaced resources use the default assets, as shown below:

```
# non-namespaced
/public
/public/images
/public/javascripts
/public/stylesheets

# namespaced
/admin
/admin/images
/admin/javascripts
/admin/stylesheets
```

I have seen information on changing `config/environments/*.rb` or `config/application.rb` and use something like the following, but can not find any examples to do this based on the namespace.

Keep in mind there will ONLY be two namespaces ADMIN and PUBLIC.

```
config.action_controller.asset_path
config.action_controller.asset_dir
config.action_controller.javascripts_dir
config.action_controller.stylesheets_dir
config.action_controller.images_dir
```

**Question:** It seems this should be possible.  So my question(s) is, is this possible?  If so, how? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is going on a bit more of a limb than I'm used to, but I hope it helps.

The first step would be to identify some code that is run only for your `admin` namespace. I would probably create another application controller, perhaps `admin_application_controller.rb`, that extended from your base application controller, and then extend from *that* controller for all your admin controllers. For example.

```
# your basic applications controller
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  # etc
end

# your public controllers subclass it
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # stuff
end

# now your "specialized" admin controller
class AdminApplicationController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :setup_asset_paths

  def setup_asset_paths
    Rails.application.config.action_controller.assets_dir = File.expand_path(File.join(Rails.root, 'admin'))
    Rails.application.config.action_controller.javascripts_dir = File.expand_path(File.join(Rails.root, 'admin', 'javascripts'))
    Rails.application.config.action_controller.stylesheets_dir = File.expand_path(File.join(Rails.root, 'admin', 'stylesheets'))
    Rails.application.config.action_controller.page_cache_directory = File.expand_path(File.join(Rails.root, 'admin'))
  end
end

# and your admin controllers extend from THAT instead
class AdminUsersController < AdminApplicationController
  # more admin-y stuff
end
```

I'm quite interested to hear if this works for you, and if not, what problems you run into and what you find, so let us know! Good luck!!

[Edit] I've udpated the code above to reflect the members available:

```
pp Rails.application.config.action_controller
{:perform_caching=>false,
 :assets_dir=>"/Users/BinaryMuse/src/postecho/public",
 :javascripts_dir=>"/Users/BinaryMuse/src/postecho/public/javascripts",
 :stylesheets_dir=>"/Users/BinaryMuse/src/postecho/public/stylesheets",
 :page_cache_directory=>"/Users/BinaryMuse/src/postecho/public",
 :helpers_path=>["/Users/BinaryMuse/src/postecho/app/helpers"]}
```

Comment: Well I gave it a go and as luck would have it, it was a no go!  But your approach got me digging further as it seems to be the way this should happen. This led me to _railties/lib/rails/engine/configuration.rb_, where I found the actual path object. This led me to search and find this **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600364/multiple-public-folders-single-rails-installation/5307050#5307050** by Macklin, which is working, but I need to somehow inject a condition when I start the server to inspect the request and set this on the fly per request.  So that got me thinking I may need

Comment: (cont'd) to create a Rack app to include this test somewhere in the ActionView or ActionController at the point it loads the files (stylesheets etc...) and also add my own _paths.public_ equivalent _paths.admin_ (as well as /stylesheets and /javascripts).  If you have any ideas, I would love to know...  This could be a good foundation for a solid ADMIN gem keeping Public and Admin assets separate.

Comment: @William What errors did you get (if any)? I'm starting to think it should be `Rails.application.config.action_controller.assets_dir` etc. instead of just `Rails.app.config ...` Also note my solution was missing the "s" in "assets" so if you copy/pasted, sorry about that!

Comment: Well I will double check, by I am pretty sure I used _application_ and not _app_, and I used _assets_ as I copied that part of the code from where I found it in my earlier search.  It didn't throw any errors it just ignored the settings.  I think by the time we get to the Controller (even with before_filters) it's too late to change these paths, that and the ones in the _railties/lib/rails/engine/configuration.rb_ path method seem to take precedence. This lead me to believe it needs to insert itself as a Rack App or Engine/Plugin.  I will continue my investigation tomorrow (*yawn).

Comment: I never did solve this. But now it's ancient history. Could probably close this if I knew how.