# Routing pages in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new in RoR. I just added a new page hello.html in public folder. When I try to load the page on browser I get following error

```
No route matches [GET] "/hello.html"

Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

I found some solution so far but they don't really working for me. I tried following lines in routes.rb file

```
  match '/hello', to: '#hello'

  match 'hello', to: 'hello'
  match '/hello' => '#hello', :as => 'hello'
```

But Im getting same error. I know that for files in public folder I don't need to add routes but Still I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any files added in the public folder, you don't need to add routes. If the file is available as

```
public/hello.html
```

Its accessible via `localhost:3000/hello.html`

Simple! No routes.

Comment: Yes I know that for files in public folder I don't need to add routes but Still I get the same error.

Comment: Did you clear the sample routes that you have mentioned in the question?

Comment: Also, did you start from a basic-rails-app? or are you using any existing app? because, there is a way in Rails to change the default-public-directory. Ensure that it ain't the case.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600364/multiple-public-folders-single-rails-installation

Comment: Yes I cleared those sample and I started from basic rails app

Comment: Why don't you show us your codebase. Put it in GutHub and send it across. This should not take more than a min.

Comment: Thanks. I was actually running rails server in different app

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42014/discussion-between-satya-and-user1478137)