# Set public directory outside rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to make public directory outside of main Rails App directory?

Schema

```
/apps/app1
/apps/app2
/apps/this_dir_wants_to_be_public
```

I need use it with several Rails and Non-Rails Applications to manage Uploads

Comment: just create symlink file to public folder

Comment: Agree, symlink.  In your rails folder, in a command window: `ln -s /path/to/real/folder public` (you'll need to remove the existing public folder first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways I can think of:

**First**: if you are using nginx, you can configure it to first check your custom dir, and serve files from there if found, otherwise ask rails app for responce. Nginx config would look like this

```
upstream backend {
   server localhost:3000;
}
server {
   listen       80;
   server_name  whatever.com;
   root /your_static_path;
   try_files $uri $uri/index.html @backend;

   location @backend {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://backend;
   }
}
```

It is using nginx as a reverse proxy. You run thin server on 3000 port (or any other server you like), and nginx turns to it only if it could not find requested file in root directory.

**Second**: Just create symlinks

```
ln -s /apps/this_dir_wants_to_be_public /apps/rails_app/public
```

so /apps/this_dir_wants_to_be_public would be actual directory, and /apps/rails_app/public link to it. Seems absolutelly transparent for rails app and simple

Comment: The nginx solution will work fine for serving assets, but it won't help with internal rails issues: paths will be wrong for image_tag, javascript_tag etc.  Symlink is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

[Multiple public folders, single rails installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600364/multiple-public-folders-single-rails-installation)

use public.path

Symlinks may be the best approach in your case I think